# Do I need a visa to enter Finland for my connecting flight?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, international-travel, pakistani-citizens

I am traveling from Tallinn, Estonia to Lahore, Pakistan with a connecting flight in Helsinki. My temporary resident card expired a month ago. According to the laws of Estonia, I can stay up to 186 days after the expiration of my temporary resident card.

Do I need a Finland visa to get my connecting flight to Doha, which is an hour layover and from there to Lahore, Pakistan? Kindly guide me!

Best regards.

Comment: No, you would need a Schengen visa to enter Finland.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk If he flies from Estonia to Finland there is no passport control as both countries are within the schengen area. Yes, he would need a visa, but no one will check it upon entry. The passport control will be in Finland before the flight to Doha.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)

Comment: @TimLymington different situation as OP is already in the Schengen area

Comment: @Gnusper yes, he can break the law and get fined/banned/arrested, but how does this answer his question? btw, they often perform passport check on ferries from Estonia to Finland nowadays. Ooops!

Answer (score 6):

Usually, an Estonian residence permit allows you to travel freely to other Schengen countries, including Finland. The *183* days 'grace period' granted by Estonian authorities, allowing you to stay in Estonia after the expiration of the residence permit does however only apply to Estonia. You are with your expired residence permit not allowed to travel to other Schengen countries. When travelling from Estonia to Pakistan with transit in Finland, there will be no immigration control between Estonia and Finland, but you have to go through an immigration checkpoint in Finland when leaving the Schengen area. With an expired residence permit, Finnish border police will likely assess that you have overstayed.

Your easiest solution to the problem is to 'formalise' the grace period by the Estonian immigration authorities. For a 30€ fee, you will be issued a regular type D visa for the remaining grace period, which will allow you to travel to other Schengen countries as well and allow you to transit Finland on your way back to Pakistan. You can get current [information on how and where to apply for a formalisation from the Police and Border Guard](https://www.politsei.ee/en/teenused/eestis-viibimise-seaduslikud-alused/).